# pandas groupby and find max no. of consecutive occurences of 1s in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with Ids and a target value per each Id. my goal is to find the max no. of consecutive occurrences of `1's` in each group of the data frame.

original dataframe is as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Id': {0: 1,1: 1,2: 1,3: 2,4: 2,5: 2,6: 2,7: 2, 8: 2,9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2},
't_year': {0: 2021, 1: 2022, 2: 2022, 3: 2021,4: 2021,5: 2021,6: 2021,7: 2021,8: 2021,9: 2021,10: 2021,11: 2022,12: 2022},
 't_month_prx': {0: 10.0,1: 1.0,2: 2.0,3: 1.0,4: 2.0,5: 3.0,6: 6.0,7: 7.0,
 8: 8.0,9: 9.0,10: 10.0,11: 1.0,12: 2.0},
'values': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0,3: 1.0,4: 1.0,5: 1.0,6: 3.0,7: 1.0,8: 1.0,9: 1.0,10: 1.0,11: 1.0, 12: 1.0}
})
```

and my desired output is

```
pd.DataFrame({
'Id': {0: 1,1: 2},
'counts': {0: 3.0,1: 6.0}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mask with a unique value for each consecutive group of numbers (`cumsum` + `ne`/`!==`), and then groupby that and the ID, sum the numbers, and get the the max:

```
df.groupby([df['Id'], df['values'].ne(df.groupby('Id')['values'].shift(1)).cumsum()])['values'].sum().groupby(level=0).max().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Id  values
0   1     3.0
1   2     6.0
```

Comment: thank you for response, but one question what if I need to include `3` in the count as well so that final count is 3 and 7. Can you help?

Comment: Sure, that doesn't sound too hard, but what's the logic there?

Comment: logic behind this is that, I am working on month based data and `3` is that row from where new set of consecutive months starts

Comment: So basically just increment the count if the group contains `3`?

Comment: I have edited my `df`, let's say instead of 12 months I have 10 and want to find the max no. of consecutive months a customer was active

Answer (score 0):

You can first group consecutive values in the dataframe, then filter the dataframe where values contain `1` and then groupby to proceed further.

```
 df['tmp'] = (df['values'] != df['values'].shift()).cumsum() #Group Consecutive values in Dataframe
 df = df[df['values'].eq(1)].groupby(['Id', 'tmp'], as_index=False).count().groupby('Id', as_index=False)['values'].max()
```

`OUTPUT After First Line`

```
    Id  values  tmp
0    1     1.0    1
1    1     1.0    1
2    1     1.0    1
3    2     1.0    1
4    2     1.0    1
5    2     1.0    1
6    2     3.0    2
7    2     1.0    3
8    2     1.0    3
9    2     1.0    3
10   2     1.0    3
11   2     1.0    3
12   2     1.0    3
```

`Final OUTPUT`

```
   Id  values
0   1       3
1   2       6
```